# Adding Escaped Quotes to Highcharts label

Tags: html, highcharts

I want to add the clickable telephone numbers to a High Charts [Organizational](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart) Chart.

The data for each text box looks like:

```
nodes: [{
       id: 'CEO',
       title: 'The Boss',
       name: '<a href="tel: 123456">Jo Bloggs</a>',
       },{
```

I tried to escape the `"` marks with `&#39` but that did not help, i.e.:

```
nodes: [{
       id: 'CEO',
       title: 'The Boss',
       name: '<a href=&#39tel: 123456&#39>Jo Bloggs</a>',
       },{
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider use the [Unicode Character 'QUOTATION MARK' (U+0022)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm) `\u0022`.

Example:

```
nodes: [{
       id: 'CEO',
       title: 'The Boss',
       name: '<a href=\u0022tel: 123456\u0022>Jo Bloggs</a>',
       },{
```

---

See [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/Lexvcdmp/) and check the value `Employee - Torstein Hønsi`:

Example:

```
{
    id: 'CPO',
    title: 'CPO',
    name: '<a href=\u0022#\u0022>Employee - Torstein Hønsi</a>',
    image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131213/Highsoft_03998_.jpg'
}
```